# Test XML Schema definition

Tags: xml, xsd

How do You check that your XML Schema definition does what you want to do? Especially when it comes to restrictions and checks for an interface that will be used by external partners, some automatic test that makes sure that the XSD expresses what we expect would be beneficial imho. What do You think about this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of the schema is to validate instances then you test it by validating lots of valid and invalid instances. There's no way of automating this unless you (a) generate the instances from the schema, which is pointless, or (b) have some other description of the rules written (effectively) in some other schema language.

If you are concerned with other possible uses of the schema, e.g. in data binding, or as a baseline for other schemas, then you will also need tests in these areas.